# What's the difference between scrapy.cmdline.execute and executing a shell command, when running a scrapy spider in a python script?

Tags: python, scrapy

When I want to run a [scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/) spider, I could do it by calling either `scrapy.cmdline.execute(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'myspider'])` or `os.system('scrapy crawl myspider')` or `subprocess.run(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'myspider'])`.

My question is: **Why would I prefer to use scrapy.cmdline.execute over subprocess.run or os.system?**

I haven't found a word in the docs of scrapy about this function, neither does it have a docstring, but I see that it's actively used in some tutorials and code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `os.system` or `subprocess.run` both run the command in a subprocess, where as with `scrapy.cmdline.execute`  you are calling the scrapy entrypoint function directly and all of the code is then executed in the same process as the script that called the function.

- Why would you choose one over the other?

Python officially recommends using the `subprocess` module over calls to `os.system` as a general rule, (see the documentation for [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) for more information) and the `subprocess` api is easier to use and offers more control, so the `os.system` option shouldn't really be considered.

For the other two, while I am sure there are a multitude of reasons to choose one over the other, I  wouldn't recommend using either of these methods.  Scrapy offers plenty of tools that help with executing spiders from scripts such as [`CrawlerProcess`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html?highlight=crawlerprocess#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess) and [`CrawlerRunner`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html?highlight=crawlerprocess#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner) that should make it unnecessary to access the CLI from a subprocess, or call the CLI entry point function directly from your script. (although I am sure there are plenty of exceptions to this)

Instead I recommend using the CLI tool as a CLI tool, and use the `CrawlerProcess` or similar when needing control scrapy via python code.

See [Running scrapy from a script](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)  to learn more about how to run scrapy from python code.